# How to count the total number of valid pointer elements in a C++ template function?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, templates, function-templates

I recently started learning C++ after significant experience in C# and Python.

I'm attempting to create a function template that accepts a pointer parameter, then iterates through its values until the next pointer element is no longer valid. Ideally, I would like the function to accept one generic pointer parameter. It's important to mention that I *will not* be able to utilize the underlying array directly to calculate its size.

I was able to implement the same concept for a pointer of pointers, which I've included below:

```cpp
template<class T>
inline constexpr size_t len(const T *pptr[])
{
    if (pptr == nullptr) { return (const size_t)size_t(); }
    const T **begptr = &pptr[0];

    while (*pptr != nullptr)
    {
        pptr++;
    }
    return (const size_t)(pptr - begptr);
}
```

The problem with trying to implement the same concept for a normal pointer (`int *`, `char *`, etc.) is that I don't know how to conditionally break the loop once the counter is no longer valid. I was hoping that I would be able to check if the pointer address is valid, then break accordingly so the final count is accurate.

The pseudo code I have so far for my desired function is included below:

```cpp
template<class T>
inline constexpr size_t len(const T *ptr)
{
    if (ptr == nullptr) { return (const size_t)size_t(); }
    const T *begptr = &ptr[0];

    while (/*Pointer is valid*/)
    {
        ptr++;
    }
    return (const size_t)(ptr - begptr);
}
```

So is it possible for me to count the number of valid elements accurately with a loop? I'm open to using a different approach, I really just want some kind of template function that accepts a generic pointer and counts the number of elements accurately.

Thank you all in advance for your time and help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like reimplementing `std::size` (which doesn't accept pointers because they don't have size information).

Comment: If the array you pass in has no `nullptr`s, you'll perform invalid reads.  I'd suggest you keep track of the size, or use a container (e.g., `std:;vector` that deals with the size for you.

Comment: There's nothing about a random pointer that labels it as "valid" or not. C++ does not work this way. It is your responsibility to make sure all pointers you are using are valid, and point to valid objects. Furthermore, the same exact pointer can be valid at one time, and no longer valid later, even though the actual value of the pointer has not changed. Just that the object that it points to it has been destroyed. If you  then attempt to use that pointer, you will get [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: You cannot. A pointer to an array looses the information of the size. Use a c++ standard container (e.g. `std::array<T,Size>` or `std::vector<T>`) instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's an interesting page you linked, thanks for your input. This may may be a dumb question, but is there anyway to catch an exception when attempting to dereference an invalid pointer? If there is, maybe I can return from the function when the exception is caught. I have a feeling the answer is probably no...

Comment: No.  The whole deal with C++ is to manage your memory correctly so that you _don't_ dereference "invalid" pointers.

Comment: Dereferencing an invalid pointer will not result in a guaranteed exception. It might result in an exception, or it might result in whatever being dereferenced returned as random garbage, or anything in between. Unlike C# or Python, which is managed code, all your warranties have been voided, and from that point on you no longer have any expectation of anything. It's up to you to keep track of your pointers, and do whatever it's needed to only use valid pointers.

Comment: No. In C++ functions like this need to accept a [begin and an end) iterator. You can then iteratre from beginning to end. In the latest version of C++ we have extended this to allow you to specify `Ranges`. A range basic allows one object that allows you to then get a begin and end iterator from a "container".

Comment: *then iterates through it's values until the next pointer element is no longer valid.* -- There is no way to determine if a pointer is invalid, except check it for `nullptr`.  Even a pointer value that "looks good" could be invalid.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for clarifying, I'm still trying to adjust from higher-level language concepts to low-level concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do with your `len()` function looking for a `nullptr` element is only possible with a null-terminated array of pointers, eg:

```cpp
int* arr[3];
arr[0] = ... some pointer ...;
arr[1] = ... some pointer ...;
arr[2] = nullptr;

size_t arr_len = len(arr); // returns 3
```

Fail to include that terminating `nullptr` in the array and your function's loop will end up going into surrounding memory, causing *undefined behavior*:

```cpp
int* arr[3];
arr[0] = ... some pointer ...;
arr[1] = ... some pointer ...;
arr[2] = ... some pointer ...; // <-- not nullptr!

size_t arr_len = len(arr); // undefined behavior!
```

However, your `len()` function as-is cannot do the same thing with an array of non-pointers, eg:

```cpp
int arr[3];
arr[0] = ... some value ...;
arr[1] = ... some value ...;
arr[2] = ... some value ...; // <-- can't assign nullptr here!

size_t arr_len = len(arr); // DOES NOT WORK
```

You can't compare non-pointers to `nullptr`, but you can compare them to whatever `T` default-initializes to.  So, you will have to re-write the function.  You can either pass in the allocated array length as a second parameter, eg:

```cpp
template<class T>
inline constexpr size_t len(const T pptr[], size_t nump)
{
    if (!pptr) return 0;

    const T *begptr = pptr;

    while ((nump > 0) && (*pptr != T{}))
    {
        ++pptr;
        --nump;
    }

    return (pptr - begptr);
}
```

```cpp
int arr[5];
arr[0] = ... some value ...;
arr[1] = ... some value ...;
arr[2] = 0;
arr[3] = ...;
arr[4] = ...;

size_t arr_len = len(arr, 5); // returns 3
```

Or, you can take in the array *by reference* instead of *by pointer*, so you don't lose its size information, eg:

```cpp
template<class T, size_t N>
inline constexpr size_t len(const T (&pptr)[N])
{
    const T *begptr = &pptr[0];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (*pptr == T{}) break;
        ++pptr;
    }

    return (pptr - begptr);
}
```

```cpp
int arr[5];
arr[0] = ... some value ...;
arr[1] = ... some value ...;
arr[2] = 0;
arr[3] = ...;
arr[4] = ...;

size_t arr_len = len(arr); // returns 3
```

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(const T(&)[N])
{
    return N;
}

template<class T>
constexpr size_t len(const T& a)
{
    return std::distance(std::begin(a), 
                         std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
                                   nullptr));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/r7MhT4

Comment: In the 2nd version, why search for `nullptr` at all?  Why not just use `distance(begin(a), end(a))` or even `a.size()`? If `a` is iterable, it likely does not contain `nullptr` elements (assuming the elements are even pointers to begin with). If you are going to search an iterable container for `nullptr` elements, you may as well do that in your 1st version to search an array of pointers, too

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and example program, I'll go play with this and see if I can't get it to work. I appreciate your time

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understood question in such way that he has table with some size, which can contain `nullptr` and first occurrence of it signals `len` value. `size` was provided in case problem is a bit different.

Comment: @RemyLebeau So i tried using your example but I think I may not have been clear enough in my question. I am actually already able to find the length of a pointer of pointers, such as `char **`. What I am unable to do is find the length when given a pointer that is pointing to an object that is not a pointer such as `int *` or `std::string *`

Comment: @Marek Sorry, I meant to tag you in my most previous comment and not RemyLebeau

Comment: @vandavid615 what you are trying to do is only possible with a null-terminated array of pointers, not with an array of objects. In that latter scenario, the caller must pass in the actual array length as an additional parameter.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was afraid that's what I'd end up finding out. Thank you both for your help, I would have spent an unreasonable amount of time staring at my monitors trying to make this work otherwise.